# How can I install two versions of mongodb parallely in Ubuntu 12.04 ?

Tags: mongodb

I have mongod 3.0.4 installed. I followed the steps from [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/). I also want to install mongo 2.6.10 as one of my project uses it. How can I have two versions installed so that I can use either one ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run multiple mongoDB version on the same host as long as these version are not in the same Replica Set as a general rule (which judging by your question will not be a problem).

Deploy 2 installation paths.

Start the application using:

## mongod --port 12345

(where 12345 is the port you specified)
To start the exe on a different port.

Default port is 27017 if port not specified in the command.

See http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/

Example:

## Deploy:

> C:\mongo1\bin\mongod.exe
>
> C:\mongo1\data\
>
> C:\mongo2\bin\mongod.exe
>
> C:\mongo2\data\

## Execute:

> start /b c:\mongo1\bin\mongod --dbpath "c:\mongo1\data" --port 27017
>
> start /b c:\mongo2\bin\mongod --dbpath "c:\mongo2\data" --port 27050

When connecting using MONGO.exe be sure to specify port to connect to correct instance.

Comment: All you need is 2 x copies of the BIN directory.
C:\mongo1\bin\mongod.exe
C:\mongo2\bin\mongod.exe
Then simply execute each individual MONGOD.EXE with the PORT flag.

Comment: 2 interesting things: 1) poster asked about Ubuntu,  but you answered for Windows 2) why poster accepted answer for Windows